# Operation not found when calling GetMemberAsync

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, botframework

I have started implementing a microsoft bot and am simple trying to get the bot to echo the member email:

```
    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var replyText = $"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}";
        var memb = await TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.From.Id, cancellationToken);
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(memb.Email, replyText), cancellationToken);
    }
```

The call to GetMemberAsync() returns "Operation not found" in the bot emulator. I have taken the code as per the microsoft example. The bot works if I take out the call to GetMemberAsync() and echo back a hard coded string.

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: This is specific to usage in teams channel and not in emulator. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-single-member-details

Answer (score 2):

The ***TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync***  method is part of Microsoft Teams bot APIs and It will work only inside the microsoft team (ms team) channel ( teams scoped conversations ). This never work inside the emulator.

**Reference :**

1. [TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.teams.teamsinfo.getmemberasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)
2. [MS Team channel apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/team-chat-member-api-changes)